# Htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Disclaimer: Yes I did lots of searching. Yes I read the forums. Yes I tried solving this myself for 30 minutes and its just not working so I am looking for help please.

A simple htaccess rewrite rule. This is what I am using for the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/([0-9])/$ /downloads?ID=$1 [NC,L]
```

Essentially I am looking that

`www.url.com/downloads/1` runs the request of `/downloads?ID=1`

For some reason I am constantly just getting an error "nothing found" on my site. Running a wordpress site. Rest of htaccess is below

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

redirect 301 "/report2012/trends_2012/" "/2012-swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/report2011/trends_2011/" "/2011-swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/report2010/trends_2010/" "/swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/report2009/trends_2009/" "/swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/social_media/" "/social-media-report"
redirect 301 "/speaking-engagements/" "/trends-keynote"

RewriteRule ^item/([0-9])/$ /downloads?ID=$1 [NC,L]
```

Please help - I am not sure why it is not working. Thank you.

Comment: 30 minutes is not that long :) but it fails with the last line before `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`, because it has the `last` flag appended. You should place your rule _before_ the wordpress rules

Comment: Once redirected to `/downloads?ID=1`, the `.htaccess` will be loaded again and will try to match the new URL. It will match the `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` and you need to stop it by changing `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(index\.php|downloads)$ - [L]`. @giorgio is also correct about the precedence issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the code above the WP rules. I also put in a line to prevent WP form trying to interpret those download urls.

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php


# download links
RewriteRule ^downloads/([0-9])/$ /downloads?ID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^downloads - [L] 


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

redirect 301 "/report2012/trends_2012/" "/2012-swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/report2011/trends_2011/" "/2011-swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/report2010/trends_2010/" "/swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/report2009/trends_2009/" "/swanepoel-trends-report"
redirect 301 "/social_media/" "/social-media-report"
redirect 301 "/speaking-engagements/" "/trends-keynote"
```

Comment: thanks this worked great although I had to remove the second line : RewriteRule ^downloads - [L] to have it work.

Comment: I see what you tried to do with the ^downloads - [L] however if it is in my htaccess file the previous line does not work. Any thoughts on why? I tried to adapt it to a newer version and I see that wordpress loves to try and interpret my urls and mess things up.

Comment: try using `RewriteRule ^downloads$ - [L]` instead